# useState affects all instances of a Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I have a simple component below named *Idea*:

```
import './Idea.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Idea() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [ test, setTest ] = useState('');

  console.log('Idea rendered');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTest(event.target.value);
  };
  
  return (
    <form>
      <input onChange={handleChange} value={test}/>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Idea;
```

Each instance of this component is rendered using react-router via dynamic routing, as shown in the second route component below:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <main>
          <SideBar />
          <section id='main-window'>
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={ <Instructions /> } />
              <Route path="/ideas/:id" element={ <Idea/> } />
            </Routes>
          </section>
        </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

The problem is illustrated in this example: Let's say I am on route */ideas/1234* and its input value says *hello world!*. If I switch to route */ideas/5678* then the input on that route will also say *hello world!* even though I specified the input value to say otherwise upon render. If I change the input value on route */ideas/5678* the input value on route */input/1234* will change as well. They will inevitably both be the same value as if they're the same, regardless of the route. This started happening when I introduced the useState hook in the Idea component. I assume useState should reset the input value every time I change a route but this does not seem to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for the `useState` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Here's the important part for your case:

> **What does calling useState do?** It declares a “state variable”. ... This is a way to “preserve” some values between the function calls ... Normally, variables “disappear” when the function exits but state variables are preserved by React.

So by introducing useState hook to the `Idea` component, you are actually preserving the input value. If you want it to clear out based on a certain condition, like if the value of `id` from `useParams` has changed, look into `useEffect` hook. Maybe do something like:

```
useEffect(()=> {
    setTest('');
}, [id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given route `<Route path="/ideas/:id" element={<Idea />} />` when the route path param `id` changes the `Route` component doesn't unmount and mount a new instance of `Idea` as this would be wasteful, and instead it will simply rerender `Idea` with a new route path parameter provided from a routing context.

Think of this like any other React component where they rerender for one of three reasons:

1. A state update was enqueued and trigger a component rerender.
2. A prop value updated and triggered a component rerender.
3. A component's parent component rerendered.

Your code is in the third case where the URL path changed and the `Routes` component matches the best `Route` component, and since `<Route path="/ideas/:id" element={<Idea />} />` was already matched it rerenders, which rerenders `Idea`.

If the routed component needs to handle changes to the route params then it should use the `useEffect` hook to "listen" for them.

Example:

```
function Idea() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [test, setTest] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Idea rendered');
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('id updated', { id });
    setTest('');
  }, [id]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTest(event.target.value);
  };
  
  return (
    <form>
      <input onChange={handleChange} value={test} />
    </form>
  );
};
```

An alternative to listening to changes is to create a wrapper component that uses the route param as a React key on the routed component. Using this method ***will*** unmount and mount a new component instance.

Example:

```
const IdeaWrapper = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <Idea key={id} />;
};
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<Instructions />} />
  <Route path="/ideas/:id" element={<IdeaWrapper />} />
</Routes>
```

If you wanted, you could even create a custom state hook that resets on dependency updates.

Example:

```
const useResetState = (initialState, deps) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(initialState);
  }, deps);

  return [state, setState];
};
```

...

```
function Idea() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [test, setTest] = useResetState('', [id]); // <-- resets when id updates

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Idea rendered');
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTest(event.target.value);
  };
  
  return (
    <form>
      <input onChange={handleChange} value={test} />
    </form>
  );
};
```